# ES6 Modules in yeoman webapp with Babel

Tags: javascript, web-applications, yeoman, babeljs

I'm trying to write some ES6 code.  Seeing that the yeoman webapp generator automatically transpiles ES6 code for you with Babel (https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp), I decided to use that.

It was working fine until I tried to use modules.

My import looks like this:

```
import {GameEngine} from './game-engine.js';
```

My export looks like this:

```
export class GameEngine {
```

So, babel transpiles this for me, and from what I understand it actually changes the modules to requirejs by default.  When I look at my transpiled code I see this:

Import:

```
var _gameEngine = require('game-engine');
```

Export:

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', {
    value: true
});
```

I get console errors with this:

Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined @ game-engine.js:3

Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined @ main.js:1

I tried manually including requirejs but I still get errors.

Has anyone gotten modules working with yeoman webapp?  I'd love to get this working.

Thanks,
Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently had exactly the same problem. Babel is not taking care of modules management. You have to bundle all your JS files into one unique file. For that I used browserify.

I found what I needed in this article: [http://advantcomp.com/blog/ES6Modules/](https://web.archive.org/web/20150301144450/http://advantcomp.com/blog/ES6Modules) (Archived Post)

Comment: The link is now broken

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully you found a solution for that. If not, you could create a gulp task for this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    browserify = require("browserify"),
    babelify = require("babelify"),
    buffer = require('vinyl-buffer'),
    source = require('vinyl-source-stream'),
    sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

gulp.task('buildJs', function() {
    return browserify({
        entries: './app/src/app.js',
        debug: true
    })
    .transform(babelify)
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
    .pipe(buffer())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(DEST+'/src'));
});
```